# Problemas al llamar los datos con arreglos json con los textinputlayout

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, les comento que estoy realizando mi primera aplicación, la cual a la fecha me funciona bien, ahora cambie los edittext por los textinputlayout para una mejor apariencia de la aplicación, pero me ehe encontrado con varios porque, uno de ellos es el siguiente, como puedo realizar el llamado de datos a un textinputlayout con arreglo json, con los edittext,, no hay problema, trate de buscar información a través de la web como traspasar datos de un textinputlayout a un edittext o textview, pero no encontré nada, aquí les muestro el código que utilizo para la búsqueda de datos.

```
Public class Frmvaloruf extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextInputLayout txtbusqueda7, txtaño;
private EditText et_busqueda,et_filas,et_año,et_mes,et_fecha,et_valor,et_activo,colFilas,colAño,colMes,colFecha,colValor;
Button cmdingresar, cmdmodificar, btn_eliminar, btn_limpiar, btn_salir;
TableLayout tbldatos,tbldatos1;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Año","Mes","Fecha","Valor U.F"};
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frmvaloruf);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    txtbusqueda7 = findViewById(R.id.txtbusqueda7);
    et_filas = findViewById(R.id.txtitem2);
    et_filas.setEnabled(false);
    txtaño = findViewById(R.id.txtaño);
    et_mes = findViewById(R.id.txtmes);
    et_fecha = findViewById(R.id.txtfecha);
    et_valor = findViewById(R.id.txtuf);
    et_activo = findViewById(R.id.txtactivo7);
    cmdingresar = findViewById(R.id.cmdingresar);
    cmdmodificar = findViewById(R.id.cmdmodificar);
    btn_eliminar = findViewById(R.id.btn_eliminar);
    btn_limpiar = findViewById(R.id.btn_limpiar);
    btn_salir = findViewById(R.id.btn_salir);
    tbldatos = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);
    tbldatos1 = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos1);
    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    txtaño.requestFocus();
    llenarSpinner();

    cmdingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.85/oficina/insertar_uf.php");
        }
    });

    cmdmodificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            modificardatos("http://192.168.1.85/oficina/editar_uf.php");
        }
    });

    btn_eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminardatos("http://192.168.1.85/oficina/eliminar_uf.php");
        }
    });

    btn_limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            limpiardatos();
        }
    });

    btn_salir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            salir();
        }
    });
}
public void buscar(View view){
    if (!validar()){
        return;
    }
        cmdingresar.setEnabled(false);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message3).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        builder.setMessage("¿Desar buscar por Mes?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                tbldatos.removeAllViews();
                tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
                tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
                String url = "http://192.168.1.85/oficina/buscar_uf1.php?Mes_UF=" + txtbusqueda7.getEditText().getText().toString();
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
                        tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
                        tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
                        tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                                View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla2, null, false);
                                colFilas=registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                                colAño=registro.findViewById(R.id.colAño);
                                colMes=registro.findViewById(R.id.colMes);
                                colFecha=registro.findViewById(R.id.colFecha);
                                colValor=registro.findViewById(R.id.colValor);
                                colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                                colAño.setText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));
                                colMes.setText(jsonObject.getString("Mes_UF"));
                                colFecha.setText(jsonObject.getString("Dia_UF"));
                                colValor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_UF"));
                                tbldatos.addView(registro);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                tbldatos.removeAllViews();
                String url = "http://192.168.1.85/oficina/buscar_uf2.php?N_Filas=" + txtbusqueda7.getEditText().getText().toString();
                JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                et_filas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                                et_año.setText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));
                                "txtaño.getEditText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));"
                                et_mes.setText(jsonObject.getString("Mes_UF"));
                                et_fecha.setText(jsonObject.getString("Dia_UF"));
                                et_valor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_UF"));
                                et_activo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Activo"));
                            } catch (JSONException e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setTitle("Oficina");
        alert.show();
}
```

en el buscar cuando el usuario pincha el no, me debe mostrar el dato en las cajas de texto, la que tengo el problema es con la que está marcada como txtaño que corresponde a un textinputlayout, no sé cómo hacerlo para que me funcione con el arreglo json y por ultimo para limpiar los textinputlayout no se utiliza el setttext(""), sino pienso que será el removiewall(), creo que debe ser así, ojala que me puedan ayudar con este problema y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: @Jorgesys te cuento que el error es el siguiente "'getEditText()' in 'com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'", averiguando en la red me recomendaron traspasar los datos a un edittext que debo declarar en el xml. el cual l hice y le puse et_año y también lo mismo, después me dijeron que bo es posible traspasar de un textinputlayout a un edittext, entonces mi consulta como se hace para que muestre los datos, o solo funciona para que sea vea bonito la aplicación y no tiene ninguna otra función, desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dentro de onResponse() de tu `JsonArrayRequest`, estás definiendo como una cadena la cual generará problemas, debes comentarla o eliminar esta línea:

```
@Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                et_filas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                                et_año.setText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));
                                //* "txtaño.getEditText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));"
                                et_mes.setText(jsonObject.getString("Mes_UF"));
                                et_fecha.setText(jsonObject.getString("Dia_UF"));
                                et_valor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_UF"));
                                et_activo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Activo"));
                            } catch (JSONException e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
```

si deseas definir el valor "Año_UF" dentro del EditText txtaño, define el texto de esta forma:

`txtaño.setText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));`

Comment: como siempre ayudando, estoy tratando de solucionar el problema de traspasar el textinputlayout a edittext y al parecer me está funcionando, cuando lo tenga listo y probado al 100% te aviso

Comment: Excelente @Hector, saludos